# Bootstrap: Modal shows even when button disabled

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, disabled-control

**Dangerous!**

I've put a bootstrap-modal onto my page as a kind-of *apply-remove dialog*, and when the remove-button (not the one on the modal; there are two remove-buttons) is disabled, the modal may not appear (when trying to remove records from database). I understand you can remove `data-toggle` property of my remove button (not a button but the `span` actually), but isn't there another option to do it? I guess it's because the `span` stays "enabled"? But how to "disable the span"? Okay, it sounds "unhealthy", but I need the `span` because I use the `data-toggle` attribute of my button for a `tooltip`.

Here are the scripts and styles I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='/blablabla/browser/bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='/blablabla/browser/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/blablabla/browser/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
```

---

Here is my button:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#applyRemoveDialog">
    <button id="btn-remove-all" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" 
        disabled="disabled" title="Remove" data-toggle="tooltip"></button>
</span>
```

---

And here is my modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="applyRemoveDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Apply Removal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button id="btn-remove" name="remove" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="">Remove</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not reversing role of the span and the button? i.e assigning `tooltip` to `span` and `modal` to the button?

Comment: Remove data-toggle="modal" and data-target="#applyRemoveDialog" from your span. Then add in button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you remove class disabled it will start working. 
EDITED:

```js
$(".btn").on("click", function (event) {         
            if ($(this).hasClass("disabled")) {
                event.stopPropagation()
            } else {
                $('#applyRemoveDialog').modal("show");
            }
        });
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->

    <button id="btn-remove-all" type="button" class="btn btn-danger disabled" 
         title="Remove" data-toggle="modal">Text 1</button>

 <button id="btn-remove-all" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" 
         title="Remove" data-toggle="modal">Text 2</button>


<div class="modal fade" id="applyRemoveDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Apply Removal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button id="btn-remove" name="remove" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="">Remove</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to only work because the variable `e` is not defined and the if-block throws an exception. Any ideas on how to make this work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can ope popup like this

```
 <span id="spanMDL">
        <button id="btn-remove-all" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" 
            disabled="disabled" title="Remove" data-toggle="tooltip"></button>
    </span>
```

in js code

```
    $("#spanMDL").click(function(){
       if(!$("#btn-remove-all").is(':disabled')){ //check if button is disabled or not
       $("#applyRemoveDialog").modal('show');//show modal
      }
    });
```

Comment: any error in console? as it is working fine at my end

Comment: have you include js files?

Comment: yeah, I've put there console.log('hello'), it appears. but the button still shows the modal. It really does.

Comment: try this in console alert($("#btn-remove-all").attr('class'));

Comment: have you removed data-toggle="modal" data-target="#applyRemoveDialog" from span in html?

Comment: nope. It says: `The page at localhost:8080 says` and then I click `Ok` and it shows the modal.

Comment: Muhammad Atif, no, I haven't. I can't do it. The remove-all button enables/disables because of different reasons and it will be a huge work with lots of questions to go through all those actions and see when those attributes may be added, and when removed.

Comment: Try to click in the MIDDLE of the button, then the modal still appears.